# object reference not to set an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, linq

in the detail view , i have the user control and i like fill the propeties of that with

```
foreach (var file in fileList.Efiles)
```

but i have the error "object reference not to set an instance of an object" for (fileList.Efiles)

please help what is the problem

the complete code is like below:

```
    public partial class DocResult : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private EDMSDataContext _DataContext;
    private int _TransmittalId;
    private int _DocId;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String tmpString1;
        String tmpString2;
        tmpString1 = Request.QueryString["DocId"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpString1))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("DocId");
        _DocId = Convert.ToInt32(tmpString1);

        tmpString2 = Request.QueryString["TransID"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpString2))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("TransID");
        _TransmittalId = Convert.ToInt32(tmpString2);

        _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
        var query = _DataContext.spDocResult(_DocId, _TransmittalId);
        DetailsView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
        spDocResultResult docresult = (spDocResultResult)DetailsView1.DataItem;
        FileTemp fileList = (FileTemp)DetailsView1.FindControl("FileTemp1");

        foreach (var file in fileList.Efiles)

        {
            file.FileName = docresult.Filename;
        }

        fileList.DataBind();

    }

}
```

Comment: Is (FileTemp)DetailsView1.FindControl("FileTemp1"); returning null?

Comment: i checked value of filelist is filetemp_ascx but efiles is null

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
if(fileList!=null)
{
   foreach (var file in fileList.Efiles)

  {
    file.FileName = docresult.Filename;
  }
 fileList.DataBind();
}
```